# App inactive state notification didn't arrive?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

When my app is active state i shown the notification using alertview ,When my app is inactive state i like to show the notification .

This is my response :

```
aps =     {
        alert =         {
            calltype = order;
            id = 194;
            info = "Dear Customer Thank you for contacting SR number for your request is SACHA4 We will contact you shortly with our service professional details.";
        };
        sound = default;
    };
```

I am splitting Those values like this:

```
NSDictionary *aps=[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    NSDictionary *alertdic=[aps objectForKey:@"alert"];
```

**INACTIVE STATE CODING:**

```
if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive)
    {

        query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into job ('id','message','calltype')values('%ld','%@','%@')",[[alertdic objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue],[alertdic objectForKey:@"info"],[alertdic objectForKey:@"calltype"]];

        UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.alertBody = [alertdic objectForKey:@"message"];
        notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];


    }
```

But notification didn't Arrive,but notification sound is arrived. i need your help friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my server response this is our previous response :

```
aps =     {
        alert =         {
            calltype = order;
            id = 194;
            info = "Dear Customer Thank you for contacting SR number for your request is SACHA4 We will contact you shortly with our service professional details.";
        };
        sound = default;
    }
```

;

Now we have changed this to like this

```
aps =     {
        alert = "Dear Customer Thank you for contacting SR number for your request is SACHAS We will contact you shortly with our service professional details.";
        calltype = order;
        id = 194;
        sound = default;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

If your application is in `Inactive status` then you can not show any alert for notification to user at that time default system notification will shown to user in system notification. so in inactivate state you have to register your app with parse push(or whatever you use) and that will send user notification but when user tap on that notification then you can check this condition `if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive)`  and in this you can show user a alert or redirect to any particular page.

Comment: if my app is inactive state then the did receive push notification method is called or not ?

Comment: No at that time it will not called. it called when user tap on that notification which he/she had received in system notification

Comment: for better testing you have nslog everything and check it in " device log " which you will get in xcode-> window -> devices

Comment: then how i have to show notification bro if app is in inactivestate. @jay

Comment: my problem is when my app is inactive state that time only sound is receiving ,none of the message is displaying.

Comment: You need to show notification from server side then there are some third party push notification provider and they will send you notification and when its send notification and your application is in inactive state then it will be add to system notification. some of name you will find here for remote notification provider are here [http://waracle.net/4-best-push-notification-services-carnival-v-urban-airship-v-push-woosh-v-parse/]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99885/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-jay).

Comment: You don't have an alert body, which makes the notification "silent" in the sense that iOS won't display a banner or system notification alert.